# Executing a stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure called `testSP` in my SQL Server Express database.

I am able to execute it using

```
exec [db_owner].[testSP]
```

but if I use `exec testSP` it doesn't work.

What is the cause of this?

I have other databases which do not exhibit this behavior.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your user probably has a different default schema. What do you get if yout run `SELECT SCHEMA_NAME()`? PS. It really helps if you post the actual error though. Stops us guessing.

Comment: for that command it returns dbo

Comment: Yes. `db_owner` is different to `dbo`. Whats the actual error message? Basically your user is set up to use dbo as it's default schema so to run anything in the db_owner schema you need to prefix it

Comment: here's the error message,
`Could not find stored procedure 'testSP'.`

im trying to change the schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your user is set up with `dbo` as it's default schema. That's pretty normal

when you run

```
exec testSP
```

it's using your default schema which is `dbo`, so it is running this:

```
exec [dbo].[testSP]
```

which doesn't exist.

When you run

```
exec [db_owner].[testSP]
```

it find and runs that stored procedure

I don't know the background but I guess someone has incorrectly/accidentally created and used a schema called `db_owner`

In all the db's that work, I guess the objects are in the dbo schema or your user is set up to use the correct schema. Go look in the object browser and compare

If you want to move the stored procedure into the `dbo` schema run this:

```
ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER [db_owner].[testSP];
```

If you want to change your users default schema to db_owner run this:

```
ALTER USER [youruser] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = db_owner;
```

I reckon the db_owner schema is an accident though.

Comment: Yes, i created the procedure with `[db_owner].[testSP]` which created a custom schema for this stored procedure. I just fixed it an hour ago. Thanks for your input nick.

Comment: Good to hear its fixed. If my answer was of use, please tick it.